# Get access to created class object from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class, object

ViewController1.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@end
```

ViewController1.m

```
@synthesize audioPlayer;
...
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[audioPlayer play];
```

How can I stop the music from method in class ViewController2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an NSNotification:

Put this where the user clicks stop music in ViewController2:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stopMusic" object:nil];
```

and in ViewController1 should have this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopTheMusic:) name:@"stopMusic" object:nil];
}

-(IBAction)stopTheMusic:(id)sender {
        [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Worked like a charm! You are the best.